Can't create custom emailAddress scalar in gqlgen
I want to create a custom emailAddress scalar in gqlgen. So if I enter a string in a graphql schema type, it should check whether that string is in "example@domain.com" format.
graphql schema

scalar EmailAddress
type User{
   name: String
   email: EmailAddress!
}

input user{
  name: String!
  email: EmailAddress!
}

type mutation{
  createUser(input: user!): User!
}

this EmailAddress is what I want to create.
I wrote a code for email as well. But there are so many imports that has to be done in various files like gqlgen.yml.
So if there's anyone who was able to create a custom email scalar in gqlgen, please share your code.
